# i have a dropdown menu - how can I trigger js function on keydown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So I have a dropdown menu from an existing input field that is generated on the go. Lets say a search of friends. How can I triger a js function when user selects a friend with enter key. I can do it with the onclick js attribute but it seems not to work with onkeydown.

```
<% auto_complete_result_and_insert.each do |friend| %>
<li onkeydown="if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {alert('sth')}">
</li>
<% end %>
```

So the question is how can I detect when a user presses enter on my listed item?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ruby on Rails, then you have the Prototype framework. Prototype will allow you to observe key down events.

Here's the link to the API:
http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/event/

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
Event.observe(id_of_element, function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode==13) {

        // do your thang

   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure LI's (or any other non-focusable items for that point) can actually handle onkeydown events, since they can't have the focus. Keys work on items with focus.

Update: yeah, they can have focus as long as they have tabindex. Just assign different tabindex="1", 2 etc to the LI items.

Here's an example of how do to it with normal form fields

```
<script>
function handleKey(e){
  var n = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (n == 13) {alert('sth')}
}
</script>
<select onkeydown="handleKey(event);">
  <option value="test">test</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `window.event` rather than `window.Event`. Also, in the `keydown` event, `keyCode` is the only property you need, regardless of browser. `handleKey` could just written `function handleKey(e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) { alert('sth'); } }`